# getting HTTP response headers with getAllResponseHeaders

Tags: android, http-headers, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, observers

I'm trying to get the http response headers every time I visit some site. I thought that using an observer like the following is enough to do it:

```
const OBS = Cc['@mozilla.org/observer-service;1'].getService(Ci.nsIObserverService); 
let httpRequestObserver ={ 
      observe: function(subject, topic, data){
          var httpChannel = subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
        if (topic == "http-on-examine-response") {
          headers=httpChannel.getAllResponseHeaders();  
        }
      }
    };
```

And in the startup method I add it then in the shutdown I remove it:

```
OBS.addObserver(httpRequestObserver, "http-on-examine-response", false);//startup methode

OBS.addObserver(httpRequestObserver, "http-on-examine-response", false);//shutdown
```

But I'm getting this in the log:

```
JavaScript Error: "httpChannel.getAllResponseHeaders is not a function"
```

Am I taking the wrong way and the operation is more complicated than it seem? this is for an extension for firefox for android and i'm not using sdk. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`nsIHttpChannel`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/protocol/http/nsIHttpChannel.idl) is not `XMLHttpRequest`. Instead `XMLhttpRequest` is a nice wrapper class around channels - not just http ones -, which also adds convenience functions such as `getAllResponseHeaders()`.

You may use `nsIHttpChannel.visitResponseHeaders` to simulate `getAllResponseHeaders`.

```
if (subject instanceof Ci.nsIHttpChannel) {
  var headers = "";
  subject.visitResponseHeaders(function(header, value) {
    headers += header + ": " + value + "\r\n";
  });
}
```